# What does "that's that" mean in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image]

I've looked it up and know that "that's that" has several meanings in different contexts. such as "a piece of cake" or "it's done(reach a conclusion)". I can't decide which meaning it is in this context, I think both are OK.

//Transcript:

> We decided the fairest way to settle this argument(whether 1 is a prime number)was to do a survey of 100 million *Murderous Maths* readers. Here are the results:
>
> is 1 a prime Number?
> Votes
>
> yes   7
>
> no    8
>
> don't know  211
>
> don't care  99999774
>
> The Murderous Maths Organization can now proudly declare that the number 1 is NOT prime by 8 votes to 7.
>
> So that's that.
> //

Comment: It's right at the bottom of the page of text, after a declaration. Why do you not think it means ""it's done"?

Comment: I appreciate that you transcribed the text in your question, in addition to the uploaded picture. That is a _really good_ practice. Thank you for doing that and making it easier for us to answer your question. Pictures are not always needed but typed out context _is_. On the other hand, this phrase is a very common phrase and easily Googlable. I understand you may not have access to Google (given that you have a Chinese last name and Google is blocked in certain countries), so I wrote up a quick answer. Next time please remember to include in your question the definitions you find.

Comment: By the way, I hope you realise how this whole page is a joke...  It wants to teach children to remember that "1 is not a prime", but the story about "doing a survey of 100 million readers" and "999 999 774 voting for 'don't care'" is just to engage the young readers, get a giggle and keep them reading a topic that is otherwise very boring for a 10-year-old.

Comment: See [Does “that's that” always mean “end of discussion”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15635/does-thats-that-always-mean-end-of-discussion) and [Usage of “That's final”.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29996/usage-of-thats-final)

Comment: @James K: It also puts me in mind of when I was a child and there was an ad campaign for some specific brand of cat food that always ended with the byline *9 out of 10 cat owners **who expressed a preference** say their cat likes our product best*. Me and my siblings invariably used to chorus *99 out of 100 / 999 out of 1000...* (or increasingly large numbers, spoken quickly enough to still reach our punchline at the same time) ***... would rather eat mouse!***

Comment: @nick012000  neither, I am a part-time translator, my main job is rights manager in a publishing group in China.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  I thought it could also mean "it's just that easy"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*That's that* is a very idiomatic expression.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/that-s-that) gives:

> an expression that shows that something has ended:
> *I won't agree to it and that's that (= I won't discuss it any longer).*

Putting this definition into context, it just means "That concludes the matter."

Comment: I'd add that in this context it's intended for humorous effect. If 99,999,774 of ten million respondents didn't care then normally a discussion would be anything but concluded. The entire page reads as if it's tongue in cheek.

Comment: @jla That, and the claim that 100 million *Murderous Math* readers were polled (both the idea that that many were polled, and that that many exist in the first place, are ridiculous).